# collecting arabic tweets in python

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to work on Python and using it to analyze arabic tweets...

I found many scripts online everything works fine until I try to read arabic json dump files.

```
import json
import codecs
from tweepy import Cursor
from twitterclient import get_twitter_client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = get_twitter_client()

    with codecs.open('arabic.csv', 'w', encoding ='utf-8') as f:
        for page in Cursor(client.home_timeline, count = 200).pages(1):
            for status in page:
                f.write(json.dumps(status._json)+"\n")
```

I tried all possible solutions, by adding encoding, using encode and decode using utf-8-sig

but I still get this as an output

```
 "text": "RT @RTarabic_Bn: \u0645\u0628\u0627\u0634\u0631.. \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0637\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0644\u062c\u064a\u0643\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u0637\u0648\u0642 \u0645\u0646\u0637\u0642\u0629 \u0633\u0643\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0628\u0631\u0648\u0643\u0633\u064a\u0644 \u0644\u0644\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0628\u0627\u0647 \u0628\u0648\u062c\u0648\u062f \u0645\u0633\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0646  "
```

My purpose is to collect arabic tweets and saving it to a json file or csv file what ever in order to analyze it later...

Edit 1:

For future reference in case somebody is having the same issue, it looks like Its how python writes data issue. So to python its not an issue as its writing characters.
I still face difficulty in dumping the output in Arabic. But I finally found a way to at least read it. 
when opening your file, make sure that you use this

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
```

if you read it as Bytes you will be able to handle it in the original language, try pringing and it works>

Answer (score 1):

twitter returns information about tweet language, check **'lang'** param in response and filter tweets by **response['lang'] == 'ar'**, where **'ar'** means arabic

Comment: Thanks for  your timely response, my issue is with the returned data... its supposed to print in Arabic... I tried using the utf-8 encoding but I still get this \u0645\u0628\u0627\u0634\u0631 instead of getting arabic letters

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: "tweet_text".encode('cp1252').decode('cp1256') I found this solution try it))

Comment: I am using python 3.6... still now working, after searching it looks like this solution is valid for python 2.7

Comment: I get what you are pointing at... it makes sense although i failed to access the entity tweet_text... what I am trying to do now is to save the tweet with the field 'text' encoded in a csv file or whatever file I can read later.

Answer (score 0):

include the lang parameter. for example, for the Sinhala language, the code will be like below.

```
import tweepy

# Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = "XXXXXXXXX"
consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXXXX"
access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q='තම්බි
                           rpp=100,
                           include_entities=True,
                           lang="si").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```